# How to use animation on a rotated element in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have an div element that is rotated 90 degree by default. Now I want to apply animation effect on it on click. Is there a way to preserve the rotation effect throughout the life of animation?

When I use animation, I was able to define the CSS effect on 0%, 50%, and 100% of the life of animation. But the element has a random chance of rotating 90 or -90 degrees, I cannot put a hardcoded rotation within the keyframes definition.

```html
<div class="solid clock ani">&#10004;</div>
<div class="solid counterclock ani">&#10004;</div>
```

```css
.solid {width:50px; height:50px}
.clock {transform: rotate(90deg)} /*clock-wise rotation*/
.counterclock {transform: rotate(-90deg)} /*counter-clock-wise rotation*/
.ani {animation popit 0.2s linear 1 forwards} /*does not preserve rotation!!*/

@keyframes popit{
    0% {
      width: 0%;
      height: 0%;
      opacity: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    50% {
      width: 150%;
      height: 150%;
      transform: translateX(-10%);
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

I would like to see if there is a way to dynamically add the rotation into the keyframes css definition above

With the code above, the element would rotate back to the original position, apply the animation and then rotate 90deg.

Ideally I want the element to stay rotated throughout the life of the animation.

Comment: you can add `infinite` as the duration.

Comment: Please can you provide a more complete example that demonstrates this _not working_ currently?

Comment: Transform is reset and rotate  is not in your animation anymore, add it aside translate to keep it. Translate can take more than 1 value. A space in between each value is the only thing needed

Comment: @G-Cyr How can I add translate to this example?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for you reply. What I had was basically a single html div that is rotated either 90deg or -90deg (defined by a class). In the animation I cannot pass the class in, but i don't know how it is possible to preserve the rotation effect

Comment: @Martin I have made some edit to the original question, hope it is more clear...

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks. I am getting what you mean. However, since the rotation direction is determined dynamically on the server side so I am not sure how I can use one animation class to achieve the animation for both clockwise rotated elements and counter-clockwise rotated elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider CSS variable to append the rotation inside the animation:

```css
.solid {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.clock {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  --d:90deg;
}

/*clock-wise rotation*/

.counterclock {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  --d:-90deg;
}


/*counter-clock-wise rotation*/

.ani {
  animation: popit 5s linear 1 forwards;
}


/*does not preserve rotation!!*/

@keyframes popit {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-10%) rotate(var(--d,0deg));
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="solid clock ani">&#10004;</div>
<div class="solid counterclock ani">&#10004;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will give it a try. Looks like exactly something I need if I can get it to work!

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

CSS animation property shorthand-syntax:

```
animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode play-state;
```

So in your case, you can define it as:

```
animation: popit 5s linear infinite forwards;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the question I had was that the animation starts by rotating back the div element to 0deg and then apply the animation and then rotate it back to 90deg. What I wanted is throughout the animation, the rotation effect preserves.